# How to solve the problem with auto size collection view?

Tags: ios, swift

Without calling `reloadData()` it displays everything correctly, like this:

**Correct Display**

[image]

But after calling reloadData ()

**wrong display**

[image]

The problem occurs just after calling reloadData ()

My collection view cell code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pronunciationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
        contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
    ])
}
```

**constraints**

[image]

Comment: try increasing the compression priority of that label

Comment: Any code in `sizeForItem` ??

Comment: It would be better if you explained/highlighted difference between right and wrong image. It's hard to see what exactly is happening there.